# Is there a way to convert an Object[] array to char[] array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
class Solution {
    char[] make(String s){
        Stack<Character> st= new Stack<Character>();
        for(char c:s.toCharArray()){
            if(c!='#'){
                st.push(c);
            }
            else if(!st.isEmpty()){
                st.pop();
            }
        }
        return (char [])(st.toArray());
    }
    public boolean backspaceCompare(String S, String T) {
        char[] ch1=make(S);
        char[] ch2=make(T);
        int i,j;
        if(ch1.length!=ch2.length)
            return false;
        else{
            for(i=0;i<ch1.length;i++){
                if(ch1[i]!=ch2[i]){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

the above piece of code gives an error:
 incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to char[]
        return (char [])(st.toArray());

i tried to typecast using Character[] but that cannot be converted to char[] apparantely

is there any mthod in java to convert an Object[] containing characters only into a character array i.e char[] so that i can return a char[] from the make function

Comment: No, you should switch the return type to Character[] or Object[] or manually copy the array.

Comment: you can try this:
```String stringArray[] = Arrays.stream(objArray).toArray(String[]::new);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have to it's easy to program:

```
Character[] refArray = (Character[]) st.toArray();
char[] charArray = new char[refArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < refArray.length; i++) {
    charArray[i] = refArray[i];
}
return charArray;
```

Note that a more specified collection should probably be preferred, possibly something build around a `StringBuilder` or something similar (if you have many characters). It's rather wasteful to use a reference per character, after all (but yeah, computers nowadays).

Answer (score 0):

If you work with `Character` only you can use the [toArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#toArray(T[])) `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` override

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this Vector in the
>   correct order; the runtime type of the returned array is that of the
>   specified array.

```
Character[] make(String s){
    Stack<Character> st = new Stack<Character>();
    //...
    return st.toArray(new Character[st.size()]);
}

public boolean backspaceCompare(String S, String T) {
    Character[] ch1 = make(S);
    Character[] ch2 = make(T);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following `Stream` API code should work, while collecting with `StringBuilder` also accepts `Object` elements:

```
char[] chars = Stream.of(st.toArray())
  .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
  .toString()
  .toCharArray();
```

You might want to convert your source array into a `Character[]` array first, depending on your use case:

```
st.toArray(Character[]::new);
```

The `Stream` conversion via `StringBuilder` above should work with both source arrays.